# Can I manage file-sharing on a Windows host from a Unix host?

Tags: windows-7, file-sharing, freebsd

I have a Windows computer with a lot of hard drives.  I don't really want to expose it to anything because I have no idea what hardening on Windows involves.  If possible, I'd like to permanently mount the drives on another box (in this case, my old ThinkPad running FreeBSD) and share them around my home network/to trusted outside sources.

How can I make the storage on the Windows computer totally unaccessible, except by this one other computer?

Answer (score 1):

Connect the windows-7 computer to the network *only* through the FreeBSD machine. That way the FreeBSD machine can control all access via filtering and port forwarding.

Personally, I would rather store the data on a FreeBSD server! It is better suited for the purpose.

Comment: I'm agree with this proposition, share from the freebsd-box for the WIN-7 box and the rest of your network –

Answer (score 0):

Look to Smbfs,

```
mount_smbfs //[username]@[servername][:port]/[share] /[local mount name and path]
```

see :

http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mount_smbfs&sektion=8 for mount command
or
http://blog.up-link.ro/freebsd-how-to-mount-smb-cifs-shares-under-freebsd/ for fstab syntaxe

You need two network interfaces on your Freebsd box, 
configure two RFC 1918 ip network  networks :

- One for the WIN 7 box and the first Freebsd Interface
- One for the second network interface of the freebsd Box and the rest of your network

mount your WIN-7 one the freebsd-box, share it over your network or DMZ, with ftp, web, etc ...

But please don't try to do SAMBA over smb-fs
or NFS over smb-fs, it's a very bad idea, i hope this is not possible :)

if you want to share dd, with the rest of the network, connect it physically on the freebsd box and use SAMBA

Comment: if you want to share from freebsd, so, look to SAMBA, and connect your physical DD onto the freebsd Box, samba is in the ports tree